# Conversion of JSON to Object

Tags: java, spring-boot, casting, jackson, objectmapper

I am working on a Microservices Project in Java, using Spring Boot and Eureka.
I came across a scenario where I fetch the data from another microservice using-

```
        List<Rating> ratings=(List<Rating>) restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8083/microservices/rating/get-all-ratings-by-user?userId=ddb8e2a9-ac6f-460d-a43e-eae23d18450c", Map.class).get("data");
```

I get a warning on this line-
[image]

**Explanation-**
I get the following response from the URL I used above-

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ratingId": "6140b240-9a97-430d-92b9-0fcfa8edc96f",
            "userId": "ddb8e2a9-ac6f-460d-a43e-eae23d18450c",
            "hotelId": "1093aa3f-8529-4330-8ce8-caa82546200b",
            "rating": 4,
            "feedback": "Died peacefully"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Success",
    "code": "2000"
}
```

**Aim-** I want to extract the list of **Rating** objects from the response's **data** field and store it as a **List**. Further, I want to iterate over it and perform other operations.

1. I convert it to a **Map** (Map.class passed in **getForObject() method**).
2. I get the list of type **Map** using **.get("data").**
3. This is type casted to **List<Rating>**.
   **My Question-**
   Using this above approach I am able to obtain a list of objects of **Rating** class. But, can somebody explain **how this map (obtained using .get("data")) automatically gets converted to List using simple type conversion?** The code doesn't seem to use any Object Mapper like Jackson. Also, I am getting a warning. Is there any way to remove it?  I can send the List as it is to a GET request.
   **But If I try to use a method on the List I get errors-**
   **Follow Up-**
4. I tried using stream() and map() on the List I obtained above, but got an error-

```
 ratings=ratings.stream().map(rating->{
            //api call to hotel service to obtain the hotel
            Hotel hotel=(Hotel) restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8086/microservices/hotel/get-hotel-by-id?hotelId="+rating.getHotelId(), Map.class).getBody().get("data");
            logger.info("fetched hotel: ", hotel);
            rating.setHotel(hotel);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Got a compile-time error on the **.map()**-

[image]

5. **forEach() gives class cast exception-**

```
  ratings.forEach((rating)->{
            //api call to hotel service to obtain the hotel
            Hotel hotel=(Hotel) restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8086/microservices/hotel/get-hotel-by-id?hotelId="+rating.getHotelId(), Map.class).getBody().get("data");
            logger.info("fetched hotel: ", hotel);
            rating.setHotel(hotel);
      });
```

Error on **forEach()**-

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.example.user_service.entities.Rating (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.example.user_service.entities.Rating is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @db2af5f)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.example.user_service.ServiceImpl.UserServiceImpl.getUser(UserServiceImpl.java:84) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.example.user_service.controller.UserController.getUserById(UserController.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: Does it work? I'd expect `get("data")` to return a `List<Map<String, Object>>`, not a `List<Rating>`.

Comment: Yes, its working but with a warning as I stated above. I also expect the same, that's the reason I posted this question to have a better understanding.

Comment: When I say "working", I meant "can you execute it without (class cast) exceptions"? It's compiling fine, but will it work at runtime?

Comment: Please check the question, I have elaborated the problem a bit more for better understanding.

Comment: coder001 the class cast exception you encounter with forEach is exactly what I wrote in my first two comments: "cannot cast LinkedHashMap to Rating" (because `get("data")` returns a `List<Map<String, Object>>`, not a `List<Rating>`. So the answer to your question "how is it possible that it is converted to a ratings list?" is "it's not possible and that's not what's happening; nothing is converted, you only have maps and lists of maps"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating the task, you can convert the json response from your `RestTemplate` to a `String` value, then extract the *data* part inside of it with jackson library like below:

```
JsonNode root =mapper.readTree(json); //<--convert the json string to a JsonNode
JsonNode data = root.at("/data"); //<-- selecting the "data" part
//conversion to List<Rating> avoid problems due to list type erasure
//with the help of jackson TypeReference class
List<Rating> ratings = mapper.convertValue(data, new TypeReference<List<Rating>>() {});
```

This is achieved using the [`JsonNode#at`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#at-java.lang.String-) method that locates the specific node with *data* label inside your json, to convert it to a `List<Rating>` it is necessary to use [`TypeReference`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) to instantiate reference to generic type `List<Rating>`.